# X11: Start desktop manager inside daemon

Tags: selenium-webdriver, celery, daemon, x11, xvfb

What I'm trying to do:
Make screenshots of desktop and running program (Firefox Webdriver with Selenium, if it's important) in daemon (celeryd) in auto mode.
And I need desktop manager to be running, this is mandatory requirement. Currently I'm trying to use Fluxbox but I can switch to any other manager.

Current progress:
I can start X-server (Xvfb) in daemon and start Selenium Webdriver. Fluxbox start succeeds when I try to make it from terminal, but fails in daemon with following errors in log:
`Can't create directory

Failed to load database:

Failed to load database:/init

Retrying with: /etc/X11/fluxbox/init`

I tried to specify init-file directly, but `Can't create directory` error still exists and Fluxbox fails to start.
This might be daemon-mode restriction.

Question:
Is it possible to run *any* desktop manager inside daemon?
If yes, then how can I do this?

Comment: There's no need to have a separate daemon. Your X-server should start whatever clients you need using  `$(HOME)/.xsession`. or `$(HOME)/.xinitrc` (this includes the window manager).

Comment: I need several workers, that's why I start xvfb inside worker. I don't know if .xsession is applied to xvfb display started with selenium, I'll check this.

Comment: What's the problem with starting several workers?

Comment: There is no problem, I just need separate displays for each worker, since I'm making screenshots of these displays. From my point of view I can't use one X-server for many displays. Correct me, if I'm wrong.